# Как удалить двумерный динамический массив непосредственно в классе в C++?

Tags: c++, классы, динамические-массивы

Только начал изучать ООП и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при выполнении функции (метода) deleteArray() программа зависает и не заканчивает работу. Как сделать так, чтобы такого не происходило?

Также при использовании другого компилятора, он во время работы этой функции выводит:

> free(): double free detected in tcache 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class Matrix{
    private:
        int n;
        int **ptarray;
        
    public:
        Matrix(int length){
            n=length;
        }
        
        void fillArray(){
            ptarray=new int* [n];
            for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
                ptarray[i]=new int [n];
            }
            for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    ptarray[i][j]=rand()%11-5;
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        void showArray(){
            for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    cout<<ptarray[i][j]<<'\t';
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
        
        void deleteArray(){
            for (int i=0;i<n;n++){
                delete [] ptarray[i];
            }
        }
};
 
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int dimension;
    cout<<"Enter dimension: ";
    cin>>dimension;
    Matrix obj1(dimension);
    obj1.fillArray();
    obj1.showArray();
    obj1.deleteArray();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так у вас же ошибка! `for (int i=0;i<n;n++){`. Не `n++`, а `i++`. Внимательнее надо быть))

Answer (score 1):

Вот так :

```cpp
void deleteArray(){
    for (int i=0; i<n ; ++i)
        delete[] ptarray[i];
    delete[] ptarray;
}
```

Comment: Вся странность заключается в том, что не так давно я так пытался исправить ситуацию... Похоже плюсы надо мной издеваются. Как бы там не было, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

У вас главная ошибка в цикле -

```
for (int i=0;i<n;n++){
     delete [] ptarray[i];
```

Вы увеличиваете `n`, а не `i`, и повторно удаляете уже удаленное.

и не удаляете сам `ptarray`.

и еще у вас нет нормального конструктора копирования, а сгенерированный будет копировать сами указатели, и вы получите проблемы.

и вы получите их при присваивании, если не напишете свой оператор присвыаивания.

и вы получите их, если не вызовите `fillArray` до деструктора, потому что у вас в конструкторе память не выделяется, так что в деструкторе будет освобождаться память по неизвестным адресам. Перенесите выделение памяти в конструктор!!